# Feedzirra cannot parse atom feeds

Tags: ruby, atom-feed, feedzirra

The idea of having a single parser for any kind of feed is great and was hoping that it would work for me.
I have been trying to get feedzirra to parse atom feeds.
specifically:

1. http://pindancing.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default
2. http://adam.heroku.com/feed

Those are just 2 that I tried with the problem is that feedzirra cannot parse the 
entry URL. It always comes out *nil*

```
feed = Feedzirra::Feed.fetch_and_parse(search.rss_feed_url)
p feed.entries.first.title
p feed.entries.first.url #=> returns nil
```

Is there anything I need to do to get it working?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hate to say "works for me", but, well, works for me:

```
require 'Feedzirra'

urls = %w{
  http://adam.heroku.com/feed
  http://pindancing.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default
}

urls.each do |url|
  feed = Feedzirra::Feed.fetch_and_parse(url)
  puts feed.entries.first.title
  puts feed.entries.first.url
end

# => Memcached, a Database?
# => http://adam.heroku.com/past/2010/7/19/memcached_a_database/
# => The answer to "Will you mentor me?" is
# => http://pindancing.blogspot.com/2010/12/answer-to-will-you-mentor-me-is.html
```

It'd help to see the rest of your code, particularly the actual parameter you're using in the `fetch_and_parse` method.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I am using 'feedzirra' (which is pauldix-feedzirra (0.0.18) gem). I tried your code on my machine and it does not work. May be I need to update the gem? my ruby version is 1.8.7

Comment: The latest version of Feedzirra is 0.0.24. That's what I'm using. I've tried on Ruby 1.8.7-p302 and Ruby 1.9.2-p136 and the above code  works fine with both.

Comment: Michael, feedzirra version could be the issue. I tried updating it but now stuck with activesupport dependencies '`activate': can't activate activesupport (>= 2.3.8, runtime) for ["feedzirra-0.0.24"], already activated activesupport-2.3.5 for ["activerecord-2.3.5"] (Gem::LoadError)' If you know of a solution let me know. I will also look around to figure out how to avoid the dependency. thanks

Comment: Finally was able to get activesupport installed and feedzirra upgraded to 0.0.24 version. Still the same result for URL value. It baffles me. Michael, can you please post what version of nokogiri gem do you have installed? that might be the last thing I check before I give up on feedzirra and try something else. Thanks

Comment: An update for feedzirra and atom feeds: It apparently is a known issue as mentioned in the google group for feedzirra http://groups.google.com/group/feedzirra/browse_thread/thread/69b330f99de94b1c

Comment: I'm using version 1.4.3.1 of Nokogiri. Someone at the end of the thread you link to mentions that using this version fixes the issue for them.

Comment: That worked. Thanks a ton Michael. gem 'nokogiri', '= 1.4.3.1' did the trick.